# Unable to connect Metamask iOS app via WalletConnect

Tags: metamask, dapps, bug, walletconnect, ios

Hi I am an iOS developer who is developing a dAAP app for a client. The app prioritizes the use of metamask iOS app. We connect to the app via WalletConnectSwift and launch Metamask app via a `https://metamask.app.link/wc?uri= ......` . Everything worked great until now however the last couple of days, when trying to connect to metamask wallet the popup View for accepting the request does not appear at all. This is happening to us even on older builds where we know for a fact that everything worked. Metamask app is not responding to our QR code either. When we try other wallet apps (For example Trust app), everything works. Does anyone have the same problem? I haven't found anywhere that metamask has any new bug that is known about. Thanks

Comment: Did you ask the metamask team if the link `https://metamask.app.link/wc` should be used? It seems odd they use that domain.

Comment: I've just managed to sort the whole thing out. Metamask actually stopped supporting the bridge for WalletConnect `https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/`. I'm not sure if they stopped supporting it on purpose. It started working again when I changed it.

Comment: Please, add it as the answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just managed to sort the whole thing out. Metamask actually stopped supporting the bridge for WalletConnect `https://safe-walletconnect.gnosis.io/`. I'm not sure if they stopped supporting it on purpose. It started working again when I changed it.

Comment: With which bridge did you change it? Because it is also not working for me as well. Can you write down the new bridge which you are using?

Comment: The new bridge I used is https://bridge.walletconnect.org